# Getting used to "superficiality"(?) in math: $n$ arbitrary linearly independent span vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that if we have $n$ linearly independent vectors that span $V$, dim$V = n$. I think what's weird for me though is the idea that if we grab another $n$ arbitrary linearly independent vectors, that those vectors also span $V$. Is it possible to miss some vectors? Does anyone have a physical example to show this is impossible?

I know it's impossible because if those $n$ arbitrary l.i. vectors didn't span $V$, the proof that dimensions are basis invariant is wrong, as we need at least one extra dimension.

But, I'm new to proof-based writing and so this feels oddly superficial: we're not literally showing these $n$ arbitrary l.i. vectors span $V$, we're just showing that if they don't, we have a contradiction, and so they must.

I say it's odd because I find it remarkable ANY $n$ l.i. vectors span a whole space.

Comment: In a sense, this *is* superficial, because the non-superficial part is exactly the proof that dimension is basis-invariant. That proof should contain a less superficial argument for why $n$ arbitrary linearly independent vectors span $V$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the case $n=2$ is an informative example because it's easy to visualize. Consider the plane $\mathbb R^2$. Any two linearly independent vectors in the plane span the whole plane.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to understand the idea a bit better once you learn about "change of basis". To put it briefly:

- If you have a basis $b = \{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ of your vector space $V$, then every vector in $v$ has a unique representation as a linear combination of $b$.
- If you take a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$ in $V$, you can write each of them in terms of $b$, and this gives you $n$ linear equations of the form $c_i = \lambda_{i,1} b_1 + \ldots + \lambda_{i,n} b_n$.
- You now have $n$ linear equations, which you can rearrange and solve for $b_j$ in terms of $c_i$, i.e. you can write $b_j = \omega_{j,1} c_1 + \ldots +\omega_{j,n} c_n$. (Proving that you can do this without making use of existing vector space stuff is a little tricky, but possible.)
- Now, since $b$ spans $V$, you can take any vector $v = a_1 b_1 + \ldots + a_n b_n$ and substitute in so you get $v = a_1(\omega_{1,1} c_1 + \ldots + \omega_{n,1} c_n) + \ldots + a_n(\omega_{n,1} c_1 + \ldots + \omega_{n,n})$ and expand that out, and now you've written $v$ as a linear combination of $c_i$, which means that $c$ must also span $V$.

So in other words, given two potential basis sets, you can always replace one of them with the other, and this only works because the process involves solving a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns (in the sense of not knowing how to express $b_j$ in terms of $c_i$), which is why the dimension of $V$ must be a fixed quantity regardless of what basis you use.